# np-hard -closure

Tags: np-hard

`if l1 is in NP-HARD`, so for every L2!=empty set, `l1*l2 is in np-hard`.

when:

```
l1*l2={(w1,w2) , w1 in L1 and w2 in L2}
```

Is it true or false and why?

I can't approve it but I also don't find counter example.

Comment: Vote to move to [cstheory.stackexchange.com](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/)—this isn't a programming question!

Comment: Oh, good point. I also think a move might be a good idea.

Edit: On second thought, http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/ is for research questions... This questions seems a bit too simple...

Answer (score 1):

L1 * L2 is NP-hard.

Proof: Let L be a language in NP, let f be a reduction of L to L1 and let w2 be in L2. Define g(x) = (f(x), w2). Now g is a polynomial time many-to-one reduction of L to L1*L2 because clearly:

x in L <==> (f(x), w(2)) in L1*L2